# Write multiple values from json file into input php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was trying to Write multiple values from json file into input php any possible to do that

here an example

[array json try to send req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9omE.png)

[but the code error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlyNr.png)

***array on php send request***

```
$result[] = array( 
      "No_" => $record['No_'],
     "Lokasi" => $record['Location'],
     "MRDate" => $record['MRDate']->format('Y-m-d'),
     "Description" => $record['Description'],
     "UOM" => $record['UOM'],
     "QTY" => $record['QTY'],
     "Item_No" => $record['Item_No'],
     //$No_= "No_"

   );


}


   //$result = array("$MRDate", "$No_","$Lokasi","$Item_No","$Description","$UOM","$QTY");
//endwhile

// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
//sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2);
```

***on js get the req***

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  
                 
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && 
                            this.status == 200) {
                        
                          
                       
                        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  
                       

                         var tempD = myObj[0]; 
                       
                         document.getElementById
                         ("MRDate").value = tempD;
                        
                        document.getElementById
                        ("No_").value = myObj[1];
                       
                        document.getElementById
                        ("lokasi").value = myObj[2];
                        
                        document.getElementById
                        ("Item_No").value = myObj[3];
                       
                        document.getElementById
                        ("Description").value = myObj[4];
                      
                        document.getElementById
                        ("UOM").value = myObj[5];
                       
                        document.getElementById
                        ("QTY").value = myObj[6];
                        
                    }
                };
  
                // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "option_mr.php?List=" + str, true);
                  
                // Sends the request to the server
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

i try to single input it working but with multiple array error

please advice

Comment: It's not an error, you just tried to display a whole object using javascript. Objects have no visual representation. Try to select a specific property of the object and display that.

Comment: You do also have a warning message in the php that you need to fix too